# Magento 2: Logging in a custom module

Tags: magento2, module, logging, psr-logger

I created a new Magento 2 module and followed the injection-based logger object creation.

```
protected $logger;
public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
```

> Now, when I log using this logger, I get it logged as module main.
>   e.g.
>
> [2019-08-22 10:42:02] **main**.INFO: message ...

I presume, the **main** is the root logger.  How can I create my logger, so that instead of main, it will print my module name every time?

This is pretty standard practice in java to create a logger for the given class or package so that you can control the logging levels per package.  I don't even want to control the level, at least this will help me grep for my messages in my log.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check my repo: [CustomLog](https://github.com/aissyass/magento2-customlog)

Still facing any problem add comment.I will try to help you.

Comment: This repo seems nice if I had to change the target file.  I dont want to do that.  I would prefer it goes to the system.log as is, but only want to change the prefix in every log.  I am not sure how that portion is initialized.  Any comment on that?